# LinuxContainers arch-linux double login tty

Tags: virtualization, lxc, arch-linux

Since upgrading to LXC 1.0 with the new Arch Linux template when I create a new instance I have a double tty when invoking:

```
 lxc-console --name <container>
```

This is the output:

```
Arch Linux 3.19.2-1-ARCH (lxc/tty1)

arch1234 login:
Arch Linux 3.19.2-1-ARCH (pts/0)

arch1234 login:
```

When I enter the username and password the two tty's get in each others way.

The lxc container configuration is configured as follows:

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-archlinux
# Parameters passed to the template: -P vim,openssh
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)
lxc.utsname = arch1234
lxc.autodev=1
lxc.tty=1
lxc.pts=1024
lxc.network.type  = veth
lxc.network.link  = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/arch1234/rootfs
lxc.mount.fstab  = /var/lib/lxc/arch1234/fstab
lxc.arch = x86_64
#lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/archlinux.common.conf
#networking
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.veth.pair=lxc-arch1234
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.flags=up
lxc.network.name=eth0
lxc.network.mtu=1500
#cgroups
lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c *:* m
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b *:* m
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:5 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:7 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:8 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:9 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:1 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:0 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:1 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:2 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 136:* rwm
```

The fstab contains:

```
sysfs sys sysfs defaults 0 0
proc proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

Possible that it has something todo with systemd running inside the container which is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. The workaround I've found is to disable getty@lxc-tty1.service in the container:

```
lxc-attach -n arch1234 -- systemctl disable getty@lxc-tty1.service
lxc-attach -n arch1234 -- systemctl stop getty@lxc-tty1.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:
`lxc-console -t 0 -n <container>`